# I cannot link images on html

Tags: html

I tried many times but it does not work at all... and I cannot see any problem here. Very simple linking image that I want to do.. does anybody realise an issue on my html?

```
<a href="unordinary.html"><img src="Unordinary/twoandtwovernisagead.jpg" alt="Snow"></a>
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: see in console if there is any error

Comment: The code is fine, what happens as when you run the code

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your HTML.
Make sure you have the correct directory linking ans the correct file extension.
Then try using the `img` tag.

```html
<a href="unordinary.html"><img src="Unordinary/twoandtwovernisagead.jpg" alt="Snow"></a>
```

Comment: Nothing. I just told to check the directory :)

Comment: It help as an answer!  :)